# Problem in parsing multiple json objects each having multiple Arrays from a validated JSON format-JavaString

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

**Want to Process following JSON string (Validated with jsonlint.com)**

```
[{
    "label": "Hospital",
    "domain": "Health_Care",
    "synonymlabels": [{
        "label": "SHCO"
    }, {
        "label": "HCO"
    }],

    "childrenlabels": [{
        "label": "Childern_Hospital"
    }, {
        "label": "Mental_Hospital"
    }, {
        "label": "Heart_Hospital"
    }, {
        "label": "Orthopadic_Hospital"
    }, {
        "label": "General_Hospital"
    }, {
        "label": "Gynac_Hospital"
    }, {
        "label": "Cancer_Hospital"
    }, {
        "label": "Burn_Hospital"
    }, {
        "label": "Trauma_Care_Hospital"
    }]
},

{
    "label": "Doctor",
    "domain": "Health_Care",
    "synonymlabels": [{
        "label": "Clinician"
    }, {
        "label": "Physician"
    }, {
        "label": "Medical_Practitioner"
    }],

    "childrenlabels": [{
        "label": "Cardiaologist"
    }, {
        "label": "Allergist"
    }, {
        "label": "Nurologist"
    }, {
        "label": "Gynacologist"
    }, {
        "label": "General_Physician"
    }, {
        "label": "Anesthetist"
    }, {
        "label": "Physiotherapist"
    }, {
        "label": "Urologist"
    }, {
        "label": "Oncologist"
    }, {
        "label": "Homeopath"
    }, {
        "label": "Dentist"
    }]
}
]
```

### Sample Code

I am able to run the following sample code and able to get the desired output. If I change JSON string i.e. object "{}" to JSON ARRAY "[{},{},{}]" to parse and necessary change in the code (no idea that how to deal with the Array) then I'm getting no results in the console. Feeling paralytic in finding my error. Please help. Struggled for almost a day in tweaking the code.

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.StringReader;  

import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader; 
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;  

public class gsontester { 
   public static void main(String args[]) { 

      String jsonString = 
         "{ \"name\":\"Mahesh Kumar\", \"age\":21,\"verified\":false,\"marks\": [100,90,85,100,14,95]}";  
      JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(jsonString));    
      try { 
         handleJsonObject(reader); 
      } 
      catch (IOException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } 
   } 

   private static void handleJsonObject(JsonReader reader) throws IOException { 
      reader.beginObject(); 
      String fieldname = null; 

      while (reader.hasNext()) { 
         JsonToken token = reader.peek(); 

         if (token.equals(JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY)) { 
            System.out.print("Marks [ "); 
            handleJsonArray(reader); 
            System.out.print("]"); 
         } else if (token.equals(JsonToken.END_OBJECT)) { 
            reader.endObject(); 
            return; 
         } else {            
            if (token.equals(JsonToken.NAME)) {     
               //get the current token 
               fieldname = reader.nextName(); 
            } 

            if ("name".equals(fieldname)) {       
               //move to next token 
               token = reader.peek(); 
               System.out.println("Name: "+reader.nextString() );           
            } 

            if("age".equals(fieldname)) { 
           //move to next token 
           token = reader.peek(); 
           System.out.println("Age:" + reader.nextInt());       
        } 

        if("verified".equals(fieldname)) { 
           //move to next token 
           token = reader.peek(); 
           System.out.println("Verified:" + reader.nextBoolean());           
        }             
     } 
  } 


}
```

### Output

```
Name: Mahesh Kumar
Age:21
Verified:false

Marks [ 100 90 85 100 14 95 ]
```

Comment: Mentioned JSON is not valid at https://jsonlint.com/. Please check yourself and does your json contain backslash at every key-pair value?

Comment: @Tot Thanks for suggesting a very useful tool. I'hv put validated json now.

Comment: Does it throw any specific error at Users/Optimight/eclipse-workspace/general/hs_err_pid4563.log?

Comment: @Tot   I have not tried yet. Totally confused... exhausted...  Actually beginner in Java programming - my first programming language. Trying to create a TreeMap with label(String) as Key and label(Object) as value.

Comment: Post that log file. Let see what's inside! Try run that file again with clean JSON.

Comment: @Tot The log file is too big to paste here; almost of double size than the allowed total characters. How do I share this log file now?

Comment: Understood, use Pastebin.com

Comment: @Tot The pastebin.com link https://pastebin.com/jwXTJy4V  Again thanks for showing another useful tool.

Comment: Can you increase the java memory and give it a run?

Comment: @Tot For such a small file and small programme, I believe the Java Memory is not the problem. I think I am mistaking on Coding Part.

Comment: Can you run it on Debug mode? I hope your using some IDE, so test it against Debug mode. It could give us some clue, were it breaks up.

Comment: @Tot  Now not getting anything in Console ... the program plainly runs ... delivers no results, any errors.

Comment: @Tot the backslash is needed at every key-pair value (As an escape character... because then only the String will remain Java String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON` has one tricky element - label arrays contain `one-element` `JSON object`. We can unwrap it using custom deserialiser. To do that let's create simple `POJO` structure which fit's `JSON` payload. `JSON` starts from `[` so it means we need to parse it as an array. All elements have the same structure. We can define it like below:

```
class Phrase {

    private String label;
    private String domain;

    @JsonAdapter(StringWrapperJsonDeserializer.class)
    @SerializedName("synonymlabels")
    private List<String> synonymLabels;

    @JsonAdapter(StringWrapperJsonDeserializer.class)
    @SerializedName("childrenlabels")
    private List<String> childrenLabels;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public List<String> getSynonymLabels() {
        return synonymLabels;
    }

    public void setSynonymLabels(List<String> synonymLabels) {
        this.synonymLabels = synonymLabels;
    }

    public List<String> getChildrenLabels() {
        return childrenLabels;
    }

    public void setChildrenLabels(List<String> childrenLabels) {
        this.childrenLabels = childrenLabels;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Phrase{" +
                "label='" + label + '\'' +
                ", domain='" + domain + '\'' +
                ", synonymLabels=" + synonymLabels +
                ", childrenLabels=" + childrenLabels +
                '}';
    }
}
```

When we want to use another name for property in `Java` comparing to what we have in `JSON` we use `SerializedName` annotation. To inform `Gson` library that we would like to handle given element in a specific way we use `JsonAdapter` annotation. In case we do not know how to write custom deserialiser it is always safe to use `Map<String, Object>` type for unknown or random `JSON` object. In case we have list of objects we can use `List<Map<String, Object>>`. Let's write simple deserialiser for labels arrays:

```
class StringWrapperJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<String>> {

    @Override
    public List<String> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            final JsonArray array = (JsonArray) json;
            final int size = array.size();
            if (size == 0) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }

            List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>(size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                JsonObject jsonElement = (JsonObject) array.get(i);
                Set<String> keys = jsonElement.keySet();
                for (String key : keys) {
                    labels.add(jsonElement.getAsJsonPrimitive(key).getAsString());
                }
            }

            return labels;
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Algorithm is quite simple: if given element is an array, iterate over it and take each object one-by-one. For each object get all keys and add corresponding values to `labels` list which is our result of deserialisation process. Example usage, could look like this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();

        Phrase[] phrases = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), Phrase[].class);
        Stream.of(phrases).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Phrase{label='Hospital', domain='Health_Care', synonymLabels=[SHCO, HCO], childrenLabels=[Childern_Hospital, Mental_Hospital, Heart_Hospital, Orthopadic_Hospital, General_Hospital, Gynac_Hospital, Cancer_Hospital, Burn_Hospital, Trauma_Care_Hospital]}
Phrase{label='Doctor', domain='Health_Care', synonymLabels=[Clinician, Physician, Medical_Practitioner], childrenLabels=[Cardiaologist, Allergist, Nurologist, Gynacologist, General_Physician, Anesthetist, Physiotherapist, Urologist, Oncologist, Homeopath, Dentist]}
```

Read also:

- [JsonAdapter](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html)
- [Serializing and Deserializing a List with Gson](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-list)

Comment: Ziober Thanks. Implemented; it worked as explained by you.

Comment: What will be advisable -  Keeping the test.json file in resource folder or hard code the test.json as JavaString in GsonApp class? How to safeguard test.json file contents from reverse engineering?

Comment: @Optimight, I guess you are talking about `Android` app. Better is to use `resource folder`. Hardcoded `String`-s make many problems with configuration and testing. If you want to keep it secure you need to encrypt it and user needs provide some password to decrypt. Try to find a solution or asked new question with `android` tag.

Comment: @ Michal Ziober I'm thinking in terms of webapi - server-side.

Comment: @Optimight, in that case it' much better to keep in file and load and cache in case it will be heavily used. It could be reverse engineered if someone take control over the server only.

Comment: Michal Ziober,  Okay. Understood.