# Gson: JsonArray cannot be cast to JsonPrimitive error

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to parse a json object containing dynamic field type using Gson:

```
{
"rows":
   [
      {
         "id": "1",
         "interventions": [
            {
               "type": "type1",
               "label": "label 1"
            },
            {
               "type": "type2",
               "label": ["label 1","label 2"]
           },
           {
              "type": "type3",
              "label": "label 3",
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
```

}

As you can see that the "label" field can be String or list of strings.

I wrote a customized deserializer to handle this issue, it works if the "interventions" field has only one element (regardless the "label" field is a string or list):

```
{"rows":
  [
     {
        "id": "1",
        "interventions": [
           {
              "type": "type1",
              "label": "label 1"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
```

}

But always throws com.google.gson.JsonArray cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive exception if there are more than one "interventions" element.

Here is the customized deserializer:

```
public class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<InterventionsModel> {

@Override
public InterventionsModel deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {

    if(je != null && je.getAsJsonObject()!=null) {

        JsonPrimitive jp = je.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("label");
        if (jp != null && jp.isString()) {

            String label = jp.getAsString();            
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(1);
            list.add(label);

            InterventionsModel interventionsModel = new InterventionsModel();
            interventionsModel.setLabel(list);

            return interventionsModel;            
        }
    }

    return new Gson().fromJson(je, InterventionsModel.class);
}
```

}

In the calling method:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder(); 
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(InterventionsModel.class, new CustomDeserializer());
    builder.setPrettyPrinting(); 
    Gson gson = builder.create();
```

The classes for the objects are:

```
public class ResultsModel {
private List<RowModel> rows;

//getter and setter ..
```

}

```
public class RowModel {
private String id;    
private List<InterventionsModel> interventions;
//getter and setter
```

}

```
public class InterventionsModel {
private String type;
private List<String> label;
//setter and getter
```

}

Could someone please help?

Comment: Take a look on very similar questions: [Mapping Json Array to Java Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098886/mapping-json-array-to-java-models), [GSON: JSON deserialization to variable type (List/String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167856/gson-json-deserialization-to-variable-type-list-string/55170378#55170378), [Problem in parsing multiple json objects each having multiple Arrays from a validated JSON format-JavaString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154226/problem-in-parsing-multiple-json-objects-each-having-multiple-arrays-from-a-vali/55170912#55170912)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create a custom de-serializer for the entire `InterventionsModel`.
Instead, just apply the `@JsonAdapter` annotation to the `List<String> label` field

```
public class InterventionsModel {
    private String type;

    @JsonAdapter(LabelsDeserializer.class)
    private List<String> label;

    // Setters and getters
}
```

And create a de-serializer for a `List<String>` type

```
public class LabelsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<String>> {
    @Override
    public List<String> deserialize(
            final JsonElement json,
            final Type typeOfT,
            final JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        // Check if the JSON object is an array or a primitive value
        if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            // Multiple Strings elements
            final JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
            final List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>(jsonArray.size());

            for (final JsonElement jsonElement : jsonArray) {
                labels.add(jsonElement.getAsString());
            }

            return labels;
        }

        // Single String element
        return Collections.singletonList(json.getAsString());
    }
}
```

---

You also have a mismatch between the Java model's field `type` and the JSON document field `intervention_type`.

As a general advice, try to always customize the shortest/smallest portion of your code, and try to build generic ones. Customizations carry a lot of work to be maintained over time.

---

For Gson `2.6.*`, use

```
public class LabelsDeserializer extends TypeAdapter<List<String>> {
    @Override
    public void write(
            final JsonWriter out,
            final List<String> labels) throws IOException {
        if (labels.size() == 1) {
            out.value(labels.get(0));
            return;
        }

        out.beginArray();

        for (final String l : labels) {
            out.value(l);
        }

        out.endArray();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        final JsonToken peek = in.peek();

        if (peek.equals(JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY)) {
            final List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
            in.beginArray();

            while (in.hasNext()) {
                labels.add(in.nextString());
            }

            in.endArray();
            return labels;
        }

        return Collections.singletonList(in.nextString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed the mismatch of type vs. intervention_type.

Comment: @Karen hi! The code I posted works out-of-the-box. I already tested it with the input you provided. Basically just copy-paste it

Comment: I followed your suggestion,  and registered the new customized deserializer as follow: builder.registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new LabelsDeserializer()); but now I am getting another error:  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject.

Comment: @Karen You **don't have** to register anything. Gson will do everything automatically. Just place the annotation as I showed.

Comment: If I don't register it, I got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @JsonAdapter value must be TypeAdapter or TypeAdapterFactory reference exception...

Comment: @Karen You're using an old version of Gson, that's why. I'll update the answer with code that works with 2.6.*

Comment: @Karen alternatively can you update to the latest one? Would be the better choice. And next time remember to specify the version you're using or people assume it's the latest

Comment: @Karen updated with a version compatible with 2.6.*. See at the bottom

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now. I accidentally added two versions of gson into my project (2.6 and 2.8), after I removed version 2.6, it worked like a charm. Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: @Karen well you also have a solution for 2.6 now ;)